# When does Brotherhood and the 2003 series split?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

So I've watched FMA: Brotherhood and Star of Milos. I want to watch conqueror of Shamballa but it seems like it continues from the  original series.  I don't want to have watch the original series since I know that the earlier portions of the story are the same as Brotherhood . Is there an episode in the original series I can start watching from that's starts to have a different story path from Brotherhood? Or should I just read about the originals ending?

Comment: Perhaps this is your question?  http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/16689/what-episode-and-what-chapter-do-fullmetal-alchemist-2003-series-and-fullmetal-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Episode 12 in brotherhood is where the story changes from the original series.

it a bit later in the original series, episode 17 or 18.

The key point is the death of hughes, that's where the story's split.

the original series stretches the backstory a bit compared to brotherhood so its worth watching from the beginning but you wont miss anything important if you start at hughes death.